# Lambda Node 8 function not awaiting method (AWS service call) to complete

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda

I'm creating an invalidation to CloudFront via API Gateway call to Lambda, but the invalidation only gets processed about 1 in 5 attempts. I'm certain I am missing something that would properly wait for the createInvalidation method to be called.

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront();

var distID = process.env.DISTRIBUTION_ID;

exports.handler = async(event) => {

  var path = (event.queryStringParameters.path);
  console.log(event.queryStringParameters.path);

  var params = {
    DistributionId: distID, 
    InvalidationBatch: { 
      CallerReference: (event.requestContext.requestId), 
      Paths: { 
        Quantity: 1, 
        Items: [
          path
        ]
      }
    }
  };

  await cloudfront.createInvalidation(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
    return data;
  });

};
```

The Lambda function completes every time and is receiving and parsing the API Gateway call just fine to populate the variables, but the createInvalidation only happens about 1 in 5 attempts, though no errors result from the other 4 attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```
// import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

exports.handler = async(event) => 
{
    const cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront();

    const distID = process.env.DISTRIBUTION_ID;
    const path = (event.queryStringParameters.path);
    console.log(event.queryStringParameters.path);

    const params = 
    {
        DistributionId: distID, 
        InvalidationBatch: 
        { 
            CallerReference: (event.requestContext.requestId), 
            Paths: { Quantity: 1,  Items: [ path ] }
        }
    };

    try
    {
        const resp = await cloudfront.createInvalidation(params).promise();

        console.log(resp);
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.error(ex);
    }
};
```